# How can I do to insert a script using React and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, tailwind-css

I am working on a project using React and Tailwind CSS and I would like to implement a modal but I have some problems to do that. Here is my code for the Modal using tailwind and react :

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import LivePortal from "./components/LivePortal";
import WorkContainer from "./components/WorkContainer";
import HomePage from "./components/Homepage";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return(
    <>
<div class="p-3">
    <button onclick="openModal(true)" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 px-4 py-2 rounded text-white focus:outline-none">
        Open Modal
    </button>
</div>

<div id="modal_overlay" class="hidden absolute inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-30 h-screen w-full flex justify-center items-start md:items-center pt-10 md:pt-0">

<div id="modal" class="pacity-0 transform -translate-y-full scale-150  relative w-10/12 md:w-1/2 h-1/2 md:h-3/4 bg-white rounded shadow-lg transition-opacity transition-transform duration-300">

    <button 
    onclick="openModal(false)"
    class="absolute -top-3 -right-3 bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 text-2xl w-10 h-10 rounded-full focus:outline-none text-white">
    &cross;
    </button>

    <div class="px-4 py-3 border-b border-gray-200">
    <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-600">Title</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full p-3">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, quis tempora! Similique, explicabo quaerat maxime corrupti tenetur blanditiis voluptas molestias totam? Quaerat laboriosam suscipit repellat aliquam blanditiis eum quos nihil.
    </div>

    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 px-4 py-3 border-t border-gray-200 w-full flex justify-end items-center gap-3">
    <button class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 px-4 py-2 rounded text-white focus:outline-none">Save</button>
    <button 
        onclick="openModal(false)"
        class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 px-4 py-2 rounded text-white focus:outline-none"
    >Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

</div>


</>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I would like to use that script below to open the modal and close it but I don't know how can I do that. Could you help me please ? Thank you very much

```
<script>
const modal_overlay = document.querySelector('#modal_overlay');
const modal = document.querySelector('#modal');

function openModal (value){
    const modalCl = modal.classList
    const overlayCl = modal_overlay

    if(value){
    overlayCl.classList.remove('hidden')
    setTimeout(() => {
        modalCl.remove('opacity-0')
        modalCl.remove('-translate-y-full')
        modalCl.remove('scale-150')
    }, 100);
    } else {
    modalCl.add('-translate-y-full')
    setTimeout(() => {
        modalCl.add('opacity-0')
        modalCl.add('scale-150')
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(() => overlayCl.classList.add('hidden'), 300);
    }
}
openModal(true)
</script>
```

You can get my code without the script tag here : https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-6funy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not going to write the code for you, because I don't think that will benefit you in the long run. But you're going to need to make a Modal Component. I would also recommend you have a read about State in React. I'll post a link for you to look at. After reading it you should have a better understanding of what you need to do to implement a Modal in React.

I would strongly recommend searching the web and learning Imperative vs Declarative Programming, useState and useEffect hooks.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html